# How to detect and print first letter after each vowel in a sentence?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wrote this code to detect and print the first letter after each vowel. It works except when I input a word with two consecutive vowels. It ignores the second vowel. For example, if I input 'school year' the result should be:

```
o
l
a
r
```

but I only get

```
o
a
```

So what am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to python and I am still learning.

```
def find_after_vowel(word):
for match in re.findall(r"[ouieaOUIEA](\w{1}|\s)", word):
      print (match)
```

Comment: You could match one or more vowels with `+`; `r'[aeiou]+(.)'` (then use `re.I` to make it case insensitive).

Comment: Does it mean you want to get a consonant into Group 2? Then why did you use `\w` and `\s`? See [`(?i)([ouiea])((?![ouiea])[a-z])`](https://regex101.com/r/wbH1JM/1).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks it worked. Where exactly should I use `re.I` ?

Comment: Read the `regex` docs and look for "flags"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No I want to list the first letters after all the vowels in a sentence. I used \w{1} to select the fist letter and \s to include the whitespace after a vowel in the selection.

Comment: I think you should update the question, now it says: *print the first letter after **a vowel*** - a single vowel. Note that `\w` matches `_` and digits, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It only worked when I input one word. When the input is "School year" it only outputs 'o' and 'a'. It should output 'o' 'l' 'a' 'r'.

Comment: And that's unexpected? If you don't want to find all occurrences, why use `.findall`? What output should you be getting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want it to find all occurrences that's why I used `.findall`. The problem is when two consecutive vowels are found in a word in a sentence, the second vowel is ignored. This happened in my code and the correction you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `finditer` and the `start` method of the resulting match objects to find the index of each match, and then use that to get the letter after each vowel:

```
import re

def find_after_vowel(word):
    for match in re.finditer(r"[ouieaOUIEA]", word):
          print word[match.start()+1] 

find_after_vowel("school year")
```

Which will output:

```
o
l
a
r
```

If you want it to return a list instead of printing the results, use:

```
import re

def find_after_vowel(word):
    after_vowels = []
    for match in re.finditer(r"[ouieaOUIEA]", word):
          after_vowels.append(word[match.start()+1])
    return after_vowels

after_vowels = find_after_vowel("school year")
print after_vowels
```

Which will output:

```
['o', 'l', 'a', 'r']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please explain the difference between  `.findall ` and  `.finditer `? I've been reading about it but I still do not understand the difference.

Comment: You're welcome. `findall` returns matches as a list of strings, whereas `finditer` returns an iterable yielding `MatchObject` instances. For this task, we want `MatchObject` instances because they contain positional information for the corresponding match i.e. the index. More information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `[ouieaOUIEA]([^ouieaOUIEA]|\s)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can try this:

```
import re

def find_after_vowel(word):
    index = re.search(r'[ouieaOUIEA]', word).span()[0] + 1
    return word[index]

print(find_after_vowel('test')) # s
print(find_after_vowel('abc')) # b
print(find_after_vowel('def')) # f
print(find_after_vowel('abcdef')) # b
```

Comment: in the last print I want  the output to be "b" and "f"